# Setear valor a input

Tags: angular

Estoy trabajando con Angular2 y tengo un formulario simple:

```
<div class='col-12'>
      <div class="form-group">
             <label class="form-control-label" for="nombre">Nombre</label>
             <input class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Ingresar nombre identificador de la Lista" #nombre="ngModel" required id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" [(ngModel)]="lista.nombre">
             <small class="form-text text-muted danger" *ngIf="send && lista.nombre === ''">Debe ingresar un nombre para la Lista de Chequeo</small>
      </div>
</div>
```

En el component tengo un objeto del tipo `Lista`

```
export class ListaChequeoEditComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Lista de Chequeo';
    lista: Lista;
    id_lista: any;

    constructor(private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute, private formDataService: FormDataService,
        private workflowService: WorkflowService, public partidaService: PartidasServiceService, public ubicacionService: UbicacionService,
        public listaService: ListaService) {
    }

    obtenerLista(){
        this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
            this.id_lista = params["id_lista"];
            this.listaService.getLista({id_lista: this.id_lista}).subscribe(
            result => {
                var objLista = new Lista(
                    result[0].nombre
                );
                this.lista = objLista;

            }, error => {
                this.loading = false;
                console.log(error);
            });
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.obtenerLista();
    }
}
```

Modelo:

```
export class Lista {
    nombre: string = '';

    constructor(nombre: string){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

Obtengo desde la llamada a una api los valores de un objeto e intento setearlos:

```
this.lista.nombre = 'Nuevo Nombre';
```

Pero recibo el error

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined

**EDICION**

Implemente la solución de Pablo, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Constructor:

```
constructor(private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute, private formDataService: FormDataService,
    private workflowService: WorkflowService, public partidaService: PartidasServiceService, public ubicacionService: UbicacionService,
    public listaService: ListaService) {
        this.lista = new Lista();
}
```

ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.obtenerLista();
}

obtenerLista(){
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.id_lista = params["id_lista"];
        this.listaService.getLista({id_lista: this.id_lista}).subscribe(
        result => {
            var objLista = new Lista();
            objLista.nombre = result[0].nombre
            this.lista = objLista;
            console.log(this.lista);

        }, error => {
            this.loading = false;
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
}
```

El valor de `this.lista` si se actualiza, lo compruebo imprimiendo, pero en el DOM no se actualizan los datos.

Comment: Creo que está claro: `this.lista` es undefined

Comment: Claro, es lo mismo que pensé, pero cuando hago `this.lista = new Lista("Hola");` tampoco funciona...

Comment: ¿Dónde inicializas? Tendrías que añadir el código del componente relativo a eso

Comment: @PabloLozano he actualizado mi codigo, llamo a una funcion que consume la api a la que llamo y obtengo los valores y los seteo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías inicializar el tributo de tu componente `lista`: Puesto que su valor se obtiene mediante una llamada asíncrona, hasta que ésta no se complete el valor de lista será `undefined`. Esto hace que la primera vez que se genera la vista el `value` de tu `input`no se pueda asignar porque al intentar acceder a `this.lista.nombre` se produce el fallo:

```
export class ListaChequeoEditComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'Lista de Chequeo';
    lista: Lista;
    id_lista: any;

    constructor(private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private formDataService: FormDataService,
        private workflowService: WorkflowService,
        public partidaService: PartidasServiceService,
        public ubicacionService: UbicacionService,
        public listaService: ListaService) {

        this.lista= new Lista('');
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Intente hacer esto pero sigue sin actualizarse los datos en el DOM. voy a dejar un log en mi pregunta para que puedas ver.

Comment: Agrego que el valor de `this.lista` si se actualiza, pero en el DOM no se muestra.

Comment: Finalmente el error no era como estaba obteniendo los datos, pero me sirvio mucho tu respuesta para ordenar mi codigo.

Comment: :( Ahora me vas a dejar con la duda!